# Where is the extension menu in gimp 2.6 for windows?

Tags: windows, gimp

In older versions of GIMP, there was an xtns menu in the toolbar box that had a script-fu menu that allowed one to create script-fu logos from scratch.

[image: the menu i'm talking about]

However, in 2.6, they have shuffled the menus around I can't find the option to create logos from scratch anymore. All I can see is the Filters->Alpha to Logo menu. Where are the logo creating versions of those scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they are at

File/Create/Logos

on the main window menu, at least in gimp 2.6.11.